# Downloading many files with repeating filenames using wget

Tags: filenames, wget

I have a file containing links to few hundred files and i need to download them all

But many of them have the same filename so by default `wget -i` downloads repeating ones as `filename.ext.number`. How can i change this pattern to something like `filename_number.ext`?

This doesn't actually have to be wget, it's just the first thing that came to my mind

Example file:

```
www.example.com/file.exe
www.example.com/unknown.png
www.example.com/different.jpg
www.example.com/file.exe
www.example.com/unknown.png
```

(The second pair is completely different than first one)

First two files are downloaded normally.
Then wget downloads the second `file.exe` but there's already a file with that name so wget renames it to `file.exe.1` (same thing with unknown.png)

I don't know the exact count of repeated filenames so there might be `file.exe.897` so i can't make a simple script to rename it afterwards. It'd be easier to just make wget rename them correctly to something like `file_897.exe`

Comment: Better add a reproductible example with sample input, expected output.   
Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We have no clue about your use case, so difficult to answer this **vague question**.

Comment: How is this a vague question? I literally just have to rename the files to make them have the correct extension and it'd be easier if wget could do it for me

Comment: What are the rules to rename if you have N times the same file name?

Comment: Like i said `file.exe.N` => `file_N.exe`

Comment: Even inserting timestamp at start would do. ```DATE_filename.exe```. Just so that the final file has correct extension

Answer (score 0):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
rename 's/(file)\.exe\.(\d+)$/$1_$2.exe/' file.exe.*
file_1.exe
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

`python` solution

```
import glob
import os
for filename in glob.glob("*.*.*[0-9]"):
    name, extension, number = filename.rsplit('.', 2)
    os.rename(filename, name + '_' + number + '.' + extension)
```

then e.g. `file.exe.897` will become `file_897.exe`, pattern used targets files which have 2 dots inside and ends with digit, `rsplit` does split twice from right, i.e. at last dot and 2nd from right dot, then `os.rename` is used to change name of file. `glob` and `os` are part of python's standard library so you do not need to install anything beyond python.